# Android Tablet version broadcast receiver.

Tags: android-emulator, android

Thanks for previous replies,

I am new to android tablet version, my application will start automatically when the device been bootup, for this i used broadcast receiver. But the receiver is not called when the tablet is reboot. I go through the online reference, what they mentioned was, from android 3 version(Tablet version) the broadcast receiver will not work automatically because of some security and to prevent the users from malwares. I am not sure the guidance would be correct or not. pls guide me.

Comment: can u please share that online reference link.

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Answer (score 0):

i too faced same problem, what i did was i set permission for boot-up.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>`

Comment: you have some idea about screen on or off? receiver permission in tablets